# "TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined" Morris JS in Angular JS directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, morris.js

I'm trying to make a directive in Angular JS to use a Morris JS graph, here's my code.

I'm getting an error in the console that point me to the "new Morris.Line({" line. What should I do? Thanks.

```
Reporting.directive('ngMorrison', function() {
    return {
        //require: '^ngModel',
        scope: {
          ngModel: '='
        },
        template: '<div id="call-chart" class="graph">test</div>',
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$q', function($scope, $http, $q) {
          $scope.getCalls = function() {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', url: '/dashboard/'}).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defer.resolve(data);
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    defer.reject(status);
                });
            return defer.promise;
          }
        }],
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrl) {
            calls = scope.getCalls();
            // get list of users
            new Morris.Line({
              // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
              element: "call-chart",
              // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
              // the chart.
              data: [
                { year: '2008', value: 20 },
                { year: '2009', value: 10 },
                { year: '2010', value: 5 },
                { year: '2011', value: 5 },
                { year: '2012', value: 20 }
              ],
              // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
              xkey: '{year}',
              // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
              ykeys: ['value'],
              // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
              // chart.
              labels: ['Value']
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This is the error I get when looking at the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'match' of undefined
    at Object.t.parseDate (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:4904), <anonymous>:1:9523)
    at n.eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:4904), <anonymous>:1:3297)
    at n.t.Grid.r.setData (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:4904), <anonymous>:1:3888)
    at n.r (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:4904), <anonymous>:1:1680)
    at new n (eval at <anonymous> (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:3:4904), <anonymous>:1:11953)
    at link (http://localhost:8000/static/js/app/directives/directives.js:59:23)
    at j (http://localhost:8000/static/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:43:157)
    at e (http://localhost:8000/static/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:38:463)
    at e (http://localhost:8000/static/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:38:480)
    at e (http://localhost:8000/static/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js:38:480) <div ng-morrison="" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope"> angular.min.js:61
```

Comment: I'm new to Angular JS so it's hard to debug when I don't know where to start. I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Start with posting the full error stack inside the question.

Comment: The problem is in the date format .this is the error in console (b.parseDate @ morris.min.js:6)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is caused when Morris runs into an issue with the xkey attribute. Change the xkey value from {year} to 'year' and that should fix it.

Play around with the example:
http://jsbin.com/uqawig/2139/edit